# Why my bootstrap navbar didn't work on mobile phone?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using rails with gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' and this is my html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand brand-name" href="#">Brand<br><p>MUSIC FESTIVAL</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="sections" href="#">LINE-UP</a></li>
        <li><a class="sections" href="#">BOLETOS</a></li>
        <li><a class="sections" href="#">FAQ'S</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="date-festival">test</a>/li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>`
```

The problem is when I visit my page on a phone the navbar is still the desktop version.
ps: I already have my bootstrap after jquery.

Comment: Did you add your meta viewport tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />` in the HTML?

Comment: @Alex thanks! it work.

Comment: Great, no problem. Remember to use Meta Viewport when working for mobiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add meta tag in head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```